# Swift Combine - How to throw an error and stop execution

Tags: swift, combine

I have an HTTP request publisher that when a 401 error is returned, I want to stop execution and display my sign in screen.

Here's part of my code:

```
cancellable = fetcher.hello(helloRequest: HelloRequest(name: self.name))
            .print("fetcher.hello")
            .catch { _ in
                // TODO: how to handle errors with request?
                Just(HelloResponse.placeHolder)
            }
            .flatMap { response -> AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Never> in
                if response.imageUrl == nil || response.imageUrl == "" {
                    // If there's no image to download just return the response
                    return Just(response).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                else {
                    // Chain together request and download image
                    return fetcher.downloadImage(url: response.imageUrl!)
                        .print("fetcher.hello.downloadImage")
                        .catch { _ in
                            // If there was an error downloading the image, replace it with a placeholder
                            Just(UIImage(named: "placeholder_square")!)
                        }
                        .map {
                            // Add image to response
                            HelloResponse(message: response.message, visitCount: response.visitCount, imageUrl: response.imageUrl, image: $0)
                        }
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { self.response = $0.self })
```

So part of the problem is the following flatMap that will download an image if necessary. The output type is AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Never> (I couldn't think of another way to do that). Right now the catch returns a placeholder model and worked fine. But now I've swallowed the error. I thought maybe Empty() publisher would work but it didn't seem right. I tried Fail() but apparently catch is a Never (makes sense). Thanks!

Comment: `tryCatch` would allow you to throw an error. I'm still confused though... `fetcher.hello` can send a failure? You don't have to `catch` it (which swallows it) - isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah fetch.hello returns AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Error>. I'll take a look at tryCatch. I want to remove the Just(HelloResponse.placeHolder). Actually for errors other than 401 I was thinking of adding a retry(), but I'm not there right now. Basically on a 401 error I want to stop (don't try to pull the image), and show my login screen. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the check for 401 happening? Is this happening in `fetch.hello`? Where the the check happens, you can return an error there. This would cause the downstream `.flatMap` to be skipped

Comment: Sorry I just reread your 1st answer. If I don't catch, I get a compile error because the flatMap is AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Never>. I wasn't sure how to have it return AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Error> (it seemed like it was getting overly complicated).

Comment: So change it to `AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Error>` and use `.setFailureType(to:)` to match the inner publishers, like `Just`

Comment: Ahh, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: @DennisCalla Please do not include the answer in an edit to the question. The answer is an _answer_. Either New Dev or you should give it _as the answer_. And you should then _accept_ that answer, thus closing the Q&A cycle. Otherwise, this just hangs out unanswered forever. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using New Dev's suggestion about setFailureType I now have it working. When I originally had the flatMap returning AnyPublisher<HelloWorld, Error> it would not compile because Just is a Never. So I changed the flatMap to Never fail but then I couldn't remove the catch because the previous failure type was Error. Adding setFailureType to the Justs in the flatMap now let me change the flatMap to return Error and I removed the catch.

```
cancellable = fetcher.hello(helloRequest: HelloRequest(name: self.name))
            .print("fetcher.hello")
            .flatMap { response -> AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Error> in
                if response.imageUrl == nil || response.imageUrl == "" {
                    // If there's no image to download just return the response
                    return Just(response)
                        .setFailureType(to: Error.self) // This allows us to set a failure type (Just is Never) so that it will match AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Error>
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                else {
                    // Chain together request and download image
                    return fetcher.downloadImage(url: response.imageUrl!)
                        .print("fetcher.hello.downloadImage")
                        .catch { _ in
                            // If there was an error downloading the image, replace it with a placeholder
                            Just(UIImage(named: "placeholder_square")!)
                                .setFailureType(to: Error.self) // This allows us to set a failure type (Just is Never) so that it will match AnyPublisher<HelloResponse, Error>
                        }
                        .map {
                            // Add image to response
                            HelloResponse(message: response.message, visitCount: response.visitCount, imageUrl: response.imageUrl, image: $0)
                        }
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Request error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
            }, receiveValue: {
                self.response = $0.self
            })
    }
```